# Manipulate: After Changing view of a Graphic, the sliders can't be used anymore

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, gui-construction

I have a new problem:
I have exported my program as a cdf standalone.
I changed the view of the graphic and now the sliders cant be used anymore. Very strange...
Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

The orange frame is the reason. The mouse still remains in the graphic.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what happens when you move the mouse using your hand and move the slider? Are you saying the mouse does not move? Also, when you say `I have a new problem` does this mean you have another post before on this and this is a follow up? If so, can you put a link to the original question?

Comment: @Nasser The day a programming bug can cause *the mouse* to physically adhere to my desk is the day I stop using computers.

Comment: Manu, please save the `bugs` tag for problems that have been *confirmed* as bugs by the community; do not place it on a new question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Computer_mouse_trap.jpg/1280px-Computer_mouse_trap.jpg

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree. But hard to interpret what `and now the sliders cant be used anymore` could mean. It can be either the mouse can't reach the slider because it is frozen, or the mouse does reach the slider, but the slider does not respond.  As typical of many questions here lately, very few information is given, and we have to sit here making guesses and asking for more information.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, I know.  And I was just having some fun with the question in the only way I am likely to. :^)

Comment: Ok, sorry, my english is not my motherlanguage :-)
I try to explain:
I change the view with my mouse, the orange frame is visible and i cant move the slider anymore

Comment: I can reproduce this weirdness with version 9.0.1 on Win7x64. I used the code from Pinguin Dirk's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40871/862). If I right click on the `Graphics3D` and select one of the view options (e.g. Front View) it will about 50% of the time make the sliders unresponsive.

Comment: BTW this is in *Mathematica*, not CDF player. The problem seems to be related to `MatrixForm` - if I remove that the problem goes away.

Comment: I need my MatrixForm to show the matrix...
And in CDF-Player there isnt that problem?

Comment: Interesting. Ctrl-Z (undo) will unstick it.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys for the help :-)
I had a little panic attack because of this error. The program of my project team is used for a meeting and a presentation and this presentation is tomorrow. Now I know that all things are working :-)

Comment: I received an internal bug report indicating that the underlying code was the same as referenced in this question.  If so, this is not a bug.  The code was something of the form `Manipulate[Graphics3D[Cone[], ViewPoint -> RotationMatrix[t, {0, 0, 1}].{1.3, -2.4, 2}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`, and the report was that rotating the graphic causes the slider to be ineffective.  If that's the problem here, then it's as designed.  Rotating the graphic wipes the `ViewPoint` option, which breaks the connection with the slider.

Answer (score 4):

The question seems to be expounded somewhat and also answered in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41227/manipulate-after-changing-view-of-a-graphic-the-sliders-cant-be-used-anymore#comment146703_41227) by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz):

> I received an internal bug report indicating that the underlying code was the same as referenced in this question. If so, this is not a bug. The code was something of the form `Manipulate[Graphics3D[Cone[], ViewPoint -> RotationMatrix[t, {0, 0, 1}].{1.3, -2.4, 2}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`, and the report was that rotating the graphic causes the slider to be ineffective. If that's the problem here, then it's as designed. Rotating the graphic wipes the `ViewPoint` option, which breaks the connection with the slider.